# just displaying only one row[gridview] in the textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(" Data Source=SYS022\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Bhagavan;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from emp3", con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (dr.Read())
     {



            txt_eid.Text = dr["eid"].ToString();
            txt_ename.Text = dr["ename"].ToString();
            txt_sal.Text = dr["esal"].ToString();


    }
```

my application contains 3 texboxes and a gridview If i click the edit link in the gridview(3 COLOUMNS) the respected row show display in the 3 textBOXES.my code is working as if i click on edit button it is displaying the last record of the gridview in the textboxes..can someone say what is the problem( here i connected from DB to gridview) please  say the bug the in this code . I know the other way to edit .. please help me . 
markup code

Comment: Can you show your markup (aspx page)?  From your description, it sounds like your code is doing exactly what you told it to do - it's filling the three TextBox's with the three values from the DataRow.  Note that if you have more than one row, the last row is what will show up in the TextBox's.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to pass an Id to your sql statement so that you edit the specific row you are trying to edit? In other words, this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from emp3", con);
```

Appears that needs to be changed to this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from emp3 where id="+GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].Text, con);
```

where Cells[0] holds the value for "eid";

Actually, the reason why it always displays the last record in your gridview is because it goes through the while loop for all the records in the emp3 table since you are doing a select * instead of doing a select * from emp3 where eid=[some_specific_id];